# Captcha de imágenes

Tags: javascript, captcha, recaptcha

estoy desnvolupando un captcha de imágenes,estoy intentando de alguna forma que las imágenes que seleccione en el frontend se guarden en una variable para poderlas verificar.
Se agradece cualquier tipo de ayuda, gracias de antemano!

Inserto el código que he hecho hasta ahora:
Este es el formato html:

````
<html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"> -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img id ="imatge0" src="imatgescaptcha/gat1.jpg" onclick="Click(this)"></td>     
                <td><img id ="imatge1" src="imatgescaptcha/gat2.jpg" onclick="Click(this)"></td>  
                <td><img id ="imatge2" src="imatgescaptcha/gat3.jpg" onclick="Click(this)"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>       
                <td><img id ="imatge3" src="imatgescaptcha/gat4.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>
                <td><img id ="imatge4" src="imatgescaptcha/gat5.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>    
                <td><img id ="imatge5" src="imatgescaptcha/inc1.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>            
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img id ="imatge6" src="imatgescaptcha/inc2.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>
                <td><img id ="imatge7" src="imatgescaptcha/inc3.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>
                <td><img id ="imatge8" src="imatgescaptcha/inc4.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>
            </tr>          
        </table>
        <div>
                <button id="validar" onclick="Validacio()">Validacio</button>
            </div> ```

I aquí el script:

``` <script>
            //Imágenes
            arraya=["gat1.jpg", "gat2.jpg", "gat3.jpg", "gat4.jpg", "gat5.jpg","inc1.jpg", "inc2.jpg", "inc3.jpg", , "inc4.jpg", "inc5.jpg"];
            var imatgescorrectes=["gat1.jpg", "gat2.jpg", "gat3.jpg", "gat4.jpg", "gat5.jpg"];
            var imatgesincorrectes=["inc1.jpg", "inc2.jpg", "inc3.jpg", "inc4.jpg", "inc5.jpg"];  
            //mezclar array
            function barrejar(){
                arraya=arraya.sort(()=> Math.random() -0.5)
            }
            barrejar();

            for(let i = 0; i<=9; i++){
                    document.getElementById("imatge"+i).src="imatgescaptcha/"+arraya[i]
            }

            //funcio click, dona estils
            function Click(imatge){
            imatge.style.outline="5px solid red";}```
````

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema? Puedes crear un array `imgsSelected` donde agregues el src de las imágenes que seleccione el usuario cuando da click en ellas.

Comment: Hola Jaime, la cosa es que no se como recoger la imagen seleccionada y ponerla en la array, soy muy nuevo en esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para guardar las imágenes en un arreglo al hacerle click a cada imagen puedes hacer los siguiente:

1. Inicializar un arreglo vacío `imagSeleccionadas` que guardará las imágenes que el usuario haya clickeado.
2. En la función que responde al evento `click` de cada imagen debes:

   - Extraer el nombre de la imagen clickeada. Puedes usar `imatge.src.split("/").pop()`.
   - Verificar si la imagen no ha sido agregada al array de `imagSeleccionadas`.
   - Si no ha sido seleccionada, agregas la imagen al arreglo.

La función click quedaría así:

```
let imagSeleccionadas = []
function Click(imatge){
  let imageName = imatge.src.split("/").pop()
  if(!imagSeleccionadas.includes(imageName))
     imagSeleccionadas.push(imageName)
  
  console.log(imagSeleccionadas)
  imatge.style.outline="5px solid red"
}
```

Te adjunto un pequeño snippet usando tu código donde cada vez que haces click en una imagen, te imprime en consola el estado actual del arreglo `imagSeleccionadas`.

```js
let arraya=["gat1.jpg", "gat2.jpg", "gat3.jpg", "gat4.jpg", "gat5.jpg","inc1.jpg", "inc2.jpg", "inc3.jpg", , "inc4.jpg", "inc5.jpg"];
var imatgescorrectes=["gat1.jpg", "gat2.jpg", "gat3.jpg", "gat4.jpg", "gat5.jpg"];
var imatgesincorrectes=["inc1.jpg", "inc2.jpg", "inc3.jpg", "inc4.jpg", "inc5.jpg"];  
            //mezclar array
function barrejar(){
    arraya=arraya.sort(()=> Math.random() -0.5)
}
barrejar();

for(let i = 0; i<=8; i++){            document.getElementById("imatge"+i).src="imatgescaptcha/"+arraya[i]
}

let imagSeleccionadas = []
function Click(imatge){
  let imageName = imatge.src.split("/").pop()
  if(!imagSeleccionadas.includes(imageName))
     imagSeleccionadas.push(imageName)
  
  console.log(imagSeleccionadas)
  imatge.style.outline="5px solid red"
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img id ="imatge0" src="imatgescaptcha/gat1.jpg" onclick="Click(this)"></td>     
        <td><img id ="imatge1" src="imatgescaptcha/gat2.jpg" onclick="Click(this)"></td>  
        <td><img id ="imatge2" src="imatgescaptcha/gat3.jpg" onclick="Click(this)"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>       
        <td><img id ="imatge3" src="imatgescaptcha/gat4.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>
        <td><img id ="imatge4" src="imatgescaptcha/gat5.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>    
        <td><img id ="imatge5" src="imatgescaptcha/inc1.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img id ="imatge6" src="imatgescaptcha/inc2.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>
        <td><img id ="imatge7" src="imatgescaptcha/inc3.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>
        <td><img id ="imatge8" src="imatgescaptcha/inc4.jpg"  onclick="Click(this)"></td>
    </tr>          
</table>
<div>
    <button id="validar" onclick="Validacio()">Validacio</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jaime :)